# Can partial sandbox objects hold more than 10K records?

Tags: sandbox, data, sandbox-refresh

Two questions:

1. If an object in production has more than 10K records, can I migrate the remainder or is that a hard limit?
2. If an object has less than 10K records, will all of the records come over during a refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial Copy Sandbox is limited to maximum 10000 records per object. Even though, the sandbox-storage is 5 GB, the 10000 limit is applied.

1. You can not add more than 10K records, as there is a limit per object.
2. As partial copy has 5 GB storage space, you can load 10000 records. Salesforce Custom Object record needs 2 KB space to store its data. Assuming this consideration, you can store less than 10000 records after refresh in Partial copy sandbox.

[What are the various record sizes?](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000193871)

Comment: These are all "soft" limits though, in some manner or other.